# Problema con WP Rest API y Laravel

Tags: laravel, wordpress

Tengo un proyecto en Laravel, que tiene instalado un WP dentro, ha funcionado correctamente siempre hasta hace unos días y no logro encontrar donde está el error:

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
file_get_contents(https://imediador.wldev.es/WP/wp-json/wp/v2/pages? 
slug=inicio&amp;_embed): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not 
Found (View: 
/var/www/vhosts/wldev.es/imediador.wldev.es/resources/views/public/home.blade.php)
```

Básicamente lo que hace la app es leer el contenido de la API para representarlo, el erro es que `https://imediador.wldev.es/WP/wp-json/wp/v2/pages` da error 404 ahora, he probado a actualizar el WP y nada, además de este error si intento abrir directamente cualquier página del WP tipo: `https://imediador.wldev.es/WP/aviso-legal/` da error 404 también por lo que entiendo que es un error de enrutamiento, pero la verdad no encuentro el motivo ni por donde puede estar la solución, el panel de admin del WP funciona correctamente, estoy totalmente perdido y no se por donde seguir...

He intentado forzar la API de WordPress instalando plugins del repositorio oficial pero tampoco funciona, he probado añadiendo index.php en la URL que he visto como solución en otros hilos, pero tampoco, si consulto el registro del servidor Apache, obtengo estos errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si compruebo el tipo de error en los registros de Apache, veo que funcionaba el 22/12 y dejó de funcionar el 28/12 (no hubo consultas entre esas fechas) estoy tratando de volver atrás en el servidor para ver si puedo arreglarlo de esa forma...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He restaurado una copia del server del 19/12 y sigo obteniendo el error aunque esa copia es de antes del error...

Comment: Y el archivo home.blade.php está en donde se supone y no se ha tocado, imagino, no?

Comment: fijate si los .htaccess de laravel y de wordpress no se estan pisando, para refrescar el .htaccess de wordpress ir a `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` y darle a save changes / aplicar cambios

Comment: @Benito-B si el home.blade.php está donde toca, el problema es que Laravel utiliza la WP rest API para leer el contenido de esas páginas y mostrarlo, y todas las URL dan error 404, también he probado a regenerar los permalinks como dice alo Malbarez pero sigue todo igual.

Comment: @aloMalbarez probé lo que indicas también pero nada sigo teniendo un error 404 al acceder a cualquiera de las páginas.

Comment: si la carpeta WP es un symlink tal vez el .htaccess de laravel no lo filtre y se lo pase al bootstrap de laravel como archivo, esto lo vas a ver como un 404 de laravel, si es así agrega `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l` ( l = ele de links ) a las condiciones de "si no es un directorio y no es un fichero pasarselo al index.php"

Comment: btw el api rest sin "pretty urls" es onda `index.php?rest_route=/wp/v2/pages`

Answer (score 0):

He podido solucionarlo reescribiendo las reglas de rewrite en el .htaccess he tenido que realizar varias pruebas hasta encontrar la forma en que funcionase correctamente.